# Import magento category and product table only

Tags: magento

We now have two magento applications. One(APP A) has category and product data which will be used in another magento application(APP B).

Because APP B has lots of new settings such as keywords, meta descriptions, etc, we can not directly use APP A's database but only category and product tables.

So is there a method to import category and product database of APP A to APP B? Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need to export and import all the database tables of categories and products

```
catalog_category_entity 

catalog_category_entity_datetime 

catalog_category_entity_decimal 

catalog_category_entity_int 

catalog_category_entity_text 

catalog_category_entity_varchar 

catalog_category_flat


catalog_product_entity 

catalog_product_entity_datetime 

catalog_product_entity_decimal 

catalog_product_entity_gallery 

catalog_product_entity_int 

catalog_product_entity_media_gallery 

catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value 

catalog_product_entity_text 

catalog_product_entity_tier_price 

catalog_product_entity_varchar 

catalog_product_link 

catalog_product_link_attribute 

catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal 

catalog_product_link_attribute_int 

catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar 

catalog_product_link_type 

catalog_product_super_attribute 

catalog_product_super_attribute_label 

catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing 

catalog_product_super_link 

catalog_product_website
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did this. I was building a new store in a test folder off root, and in the meantime production had sales, new products/customers and also inventory changes obviously.

You also need to get all mage_cataloginventory_stock tables:

```
mage_cataloginventory_stock
mage_cataloginventory_stock_item
mage_cataloginventory_stock_status
mage_cataloginventory_stock_idx
mage_cataloginventory_stock_tmp
```

- Disable compiler and cache, clear cache

In addition to the tables listed in the above answer, which are correct, upon dropping my tables (disable foreign key checks at drop, truncate didn't work from phpmyadmin), here's what to do

- import data
- re-index.

Media (images) are related to install URL, so, I was moving a production store in root directory to sub directory and all was fine.

Back target DB up first.