# How To move All Product One Domain to another Domain in Magento

Tags: magento

Hello guys,
               i develop magento site, all site done but we put product in another domain inside magento site, so how can all product would be transfer in one domain to another domain. like ex. 2000 product would be live one domain i need all product woulde be transfer in another domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can create export, and import product to magento new instance, for last you can use `magmi` this fastly. 
  If you have one instance magento, but several storage for market, and domine for him. You can create simple shell and set all products all store for example

```
foreach(Mage::getModel('catalog/product') as $_product) {
     $_product->setStore(1); // set store for product
     $_product->setWebsiteIds(array(1)); // set array id's sites for product
     $_product->save();
}
```

if you can't create export file. You can try create dump database product tables and, uply this dump to new system. If you don't have products in new instance.

see this answer for detail
[Import magento category and product table only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274670/import-magento-category-and-product-table-only)

but remember in last varient you need create full dump databases target systems.

p.s. sorry for my English.